# Failed audit on seemingly link only answer

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I recently got [audited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13043267) inside the Low Quality review queue and failed because I recommended deletion of this answer:

> You could define them yourself, but it would be simpler to use the
>   [`log`](https://crates.io/crates/log) crate, which defines several
>   macros for various purposes (see [the `log`
>   documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/log/log/index.html)).
>
> Note that the crate only provides the *frontend* for logging; you'll
>   also need to select a backend.  There's a basic example in the `log`
>   documentation, or you could use something like
>   [`env_logger`](https://crates.io/crates/env_logger) or
>   [`log4rs`](https://crates.io/crates/log4rs).

Yes, there is some explanation, but the author does not provide any code. They recommends using `log` as a debugging tool (I am not familiar with it), but doesn't provide how to use it, **only points to the documentation**.

Correct me if I am wrong here and provide some explanation; I would like to know for future reference.

Comment: Obligatory read: [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/294055).

Comment: That is an answer.  It may not be a full answer you were expecting, but it is still an answer to the question.

Comment: I know it's the American Way, but you all realise it makes literally (actually literally) no sense, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Users are not *obligated* to post code when posting an answer.  Explaining the tool that the users needs to use to solve their problem is an answer to the question.  You may feel that it's not a *good* answer, if you feel that more information is necessary in context, but explaining the approach of how to solve a problem without an implemented solution is absolutely an answer.

If you simply pretend that the answer in question has no links and only consider the text posted there, it is unquestionably an answer.  You might personally feel that it's not a *good* answer, and if you do, you're free to use a downvote to reflect that. But answers don't merit deletion just because you don't think they're *good* answers.